# use a pysical gamepad to operate android application

Tags: android, joystick, gamepad, android-controls

I need to use a gamepad (physical joystick and button) to opeate my android application. I check the related offical documentation:[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input). and my code: but no toast when I connect and operate the gamepad. Do I need other related libraries?  I didn't make any set-up action, nor did we set the manifest. 
I found that most joystick related examples are virtual joystick on the phone, but in my case, I am connecting a physical gamepad to my android application.

```
 private View.OnKeyListener mCorkyListener = new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int i, KeyEvent event) {
        // do something when the button is clicked
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), event.getKeyCode() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: you need USB or BT serial to even connect it and capture the input (unless it has a driver).

Comment: I test it after connecting the gamepad, the gamepad works well with other android applications